# How do I see multiple sprint board for different clients of a single project and get complete status of all features in TFS 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, scrum, sprint

Hi all TFS administration experts, I am a newbie in TFS administration so need some guidance.

We have a small team working in a single project and we are using TFS 2012 and template is Microsoft Visual Studio Scrum 2.1. 
Initially the structure was like:

- Team Project

  - Release 1

    - Sprint 1
    - Sprint 2
    - Sprint 3
  - Release 2

    - Sprint 1
    - Sprint 2
    - Sprint 3
       Also Area were created based on different modules of the project under team project so we could get the overall status report for each functionality.
      So we had one sprint board that managed all.
       Later we started parallel working for two different client for same product. Same team is now involved for planning and preparing project(creating epic pbi) for one client and also developing and testing for another client. So we felt need for two different sprint board at for different client. I search for a way to do it and according to my findings I created two different team with same members and created area path by the team name. That way i can see two different sprint board for each client. Current structure is:
- Team Project

  - Client 1(Area name)

    - Release 1

      - Sprint 1
      - Sprint 2
      - Sprint 3
    - Release 2

      - Sprint 1
      - Sprint 2
      - Sprint 3
  - Client 2(Area name)

    - Release 1

      - Sprint 1
      - Sprint 2
      - Sprint 3
    - Release 2

      - Sprint 1
      - Sprint 2
      - Sprint 3
         Now team can plan and work for each client at the same time. But as most features are common for both client (as product is same) I cannot get the overall progress of a module. I tried creating feature as sub area under area. But that way it gets distributed and we don't want that. 
         I am really confused what should be the area and subarea. Is there a way to manage the project for different client, so that i can get overall progress and status of a module? We work targeting the upcoming release. It is not the best practice but My expected structure is:
- Team Project

  - Client 1(Area name)

    - Release 1 (Feature A, B, C, D, E, F)

      - Sprint 1
      - Sprint 2
      - Sprint 3
    - Release 2 (Feature G, H, I)

      - Sprint 1
      - Sprint 2
      - Sprint 3
  - Client 2(Area name)

    - Release 1 (Feature B, C, D)

      - Sprint 1
      - Sprint 2
      - Sprint 3
    - Release 2

      - Sprint 1
      - Sprint 2
      - Sprint 3
         How do I manage parallel sprint board for multiple clients and get overall status for feature A?

Comment: We are using On-premises TFS

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at:

- [TFS for Cross-business line](http://nakedalm.com/tfs-cross-team-cross-business-line-work-item-tracking/)

While I was looking to model the many application model you can switch Application for Customer/Clinet. If you then use a parent Feature to represent the feature slice for your data you can easily represent what you want.